# Extraction of PCM from unknown file type

Tags: python, c, file, pcm

I have an old Korg KP3 that writes an obscure file type to SD card.  I'm pretty sure there's a PCM in there, because the original support software for it can extract it to either aiff or wav files.  That's what I want, but the original converter no longer works on MacOS Sierra.  I'm thinking of writing my own extractor, but not sure where to start.  FFMpeg doesn't help either, looks like bails out on the first null byte.  What's the best way to analyze a single binary file to see its internal structures?  Better yet, how do I extract the PCM when I find it start and end bytes?  I guess a c or python script could do it?

Comment: This file format can be anything! The fact that it can be converted to something means absolutely nothing. Are you sure the data is not just a midi file?

Comment: thanks @zvone, yeah, you're right it can be anything.  pretty sure its not midi tho, I've never heard of people encoding PCM in midi bytes, but I guess its possible?  so probs sol regardless.